# How to convert Object to String in J2ME for Nokia Asha?

Tags: java, string, object, java-me, nokia-s40

I'm developing for Nokia Asha and using Tantalum library to make my HTTP requests through the HTTPPoster class.

When the task is executed I try to get the value from the X-Session-Id header from the rest of the response headers, these are returned as a HashTable, the value in this header I need to convert it to a SHA256 hash.

But I am unable to convert the value I get from the HashTable into String.

My code looks like this:

```
final HttpPoster httpPoster = new HttpPoster(Task.FASTLANE_PRIORITY, completeURL);
        httpPoster.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPoster.setPostData(new byte[]{});
        httpPoster.chain(new Task(Task.FASTLANE_PRIORITY){

            protected Object exec(Object in) throws CancellationException,
                    TimeoutException, InterruptedException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Task is executing");

                String tmpSessionId = new String(httpPoster.getResponseHeaders().get("X-Session-Id").toString().getBytes());

                byte[] input = null;
                try {
                    input = new String("X-Session-Sig" + tmpSessionId + "test").getBytes("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Unsupported encoding exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte[] key = new byte[4];
                int tmpInt = new Random().nextInt();
                key[0] = (byte)(tmpInt >> 24);
                key[1] = (byte)(tmpInt >> 16);
                key[2] = (byte)(tmpInt >> 8);
                key[3] = (byte)(tmpInt);


                Digest digest = new SHA256Digest();
                HMac hmac = new HMac(digest);
                hmac.init(new KeyParameter(key));
                hmac.update(input, 0, input.length);
                byte[] output = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()];
                hmac.doFinal(output, 0);
                sessionId = tmpSessionId;
                sessionSig = new String(Hex.encode(output));
                System.out.println("session id " + sessionId + " session signature " + sessionSig);
                return in;
            }
            protected void onCanceled(){
                System.out.println("Request was cancelled");
            }
        });
        httpPoster.fork();
```

As you can see, in the line `String tmpSessionId = new String(httpPoster.getResponseHeaders().get("X-Session-Id").toString().getBytes());` I try to convert to String and then get the bytes but this returns **[Ljava.lang.String;@6f7159d**, not the actual value I'm looking for, even calling the method **toString()** without performing the getBytes method returns the same value.

How can I get the true value of this element in the HashTable? As far as I can see, J2ME doesn't support ObjectOutputStream class. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the **[Ljava.lang.String;@6f7159d** part meant that the object inside the HashTable was a String array.

After realizing that I just need to cast to String[]:

```
String[] stringArray = (String[]) dotREZApi.getCurrentRequest().getResponseHeaders().get("X-Session-Id");
String tmpSessionId = stringArray[0];
```

This returned to me the value I was expecting.